# Validating inputs. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java

I'm a novice at Java and I have just started a week ago.

I am trying to do a program which asks the user to input a selection of 'a', 'b' and 'c' and the number of hours.

I managed to do all of it but the problem is that:

1. When the user enters other letters rather than a.b and c the program continues running.
2. if the user enter more than '24' as the value of hours the program executes the first part of the 'if' statement only.

hereunder is my code.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class PetSelectionHw
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        String user_input="";
        String NumberOfHours="";

        int hours= 0;


        System.out.println("a) House");
        System.out.println("b) Apartment");
        System.out.println("c) Dormitory");

        Scanner User_Selection = new Scanner (System.in);
        user_input = User_Selection.next();
        char aChar = user_input.charAt(0);

        if(aChar == 'a'){
            //System.out.println("Selection is " + user_input);
        } else if(aChar == 'b'){
            //System.out.println("Selection is " + user_input);
        } else if(aChar == 'c'){
            //System.out.println("Selection is " + user_input);
        } else if(aChar == 'd' || aChar == 'z'){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Input");
        }


        NumberOfHours = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter number of hours spent at home");
        hours = Integer.parseInt(NumberOfHours);

        if(hours > 24 && hours < 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect input of hours");
        } else if (aChar == 'a' && hours >= 18){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Pot bellied pig");
        } else if (aChar == 'a' && hours >= 10 && hours <= 17){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dog");
        } else if (aChar == 'a' && hours < 10){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Snake");
        } else if (aChar == 'b' && hours >= 10){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cat");
        } else if (aChar =='b' && hours < 10){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hamster");
        }else if (aChar =='c' && hours >= 6){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fish");
        }else if (aChar =='c' && hours < 6){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ant Farm");
        }






    }




}
```

Comment: `else if(aChar == 'd' || aChar == 'z')` This is not a range check. Just use `else` without any condition.

Comment: For your second error. Name me a number that is greater than 24 `AND` smaller than zero. You meant to have an `||` instead of an `&&` here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `else`:

```
if(aChar == 'a') {
    System.out.println("Selection is " + user_input);
} else if(aChar == 'b') {
    System.out.println("Selection is " + user_input);
} else if(aChar == 'c') {
    System.out.println("Selection is " + user_input);
} else { // anything that is not 'a', 'b' or 'c'
    OptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Input");
}
```

You might even want to consider using [`switch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) with a `default` case, or the much simpler (imo):

```
if(aChar == 'a' || aChar == 'b' || aChar == 'c') { System.out.println("Selection is " + user_input); }
else { OptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Input"); }
```

As for the second question, you should use `||` (OR) not `&&` (AND) here:

```
if(hours > 24 || hours < 0)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect input of hours");
```

Comment: I would even use `if (aChar >= 'a' && aChar <= 'c')` as you can change the range more easily without that many `if` or `case` statements. Of course, it will be difficult to handle removing values which are now in range, e.g. if `aChar` should not be equal to `'b'` anymore.

Comment: You can also use `contains()` if you create an array with the valid `chars`, but it is a little out of the scope of this question I think :p